# Specifying colours and their order on plots in Likert package R

Tags: r, ggplot2, likert

I have created a diverging bar plot using the likert package and would like to change the colours. I know that likert plots are ggplot2 objects and therefore adding e.g. `scale_fill_brewer()` does change the colours. However, the colours are applied to the factor levels in alphabetical order rather than the logical order from Strongly disagree to Strongly agree and also changes the order in the legend. The data are ordered factors in the data frame.

Can anyone explain how to change the colours and specify the order in these likert plots? I have also tried `scale_fill_manual()` and `scale_fill_discrete()`.

```
library(likert)
library(RColorBrewer)

data("mass")

head(mass)
str(mass)

#FIND OUT THE COLUMN NUMBERS FOR ALL COLUMNS
data.frame(colnames(mass))

p1 = plot(likert(mass[,3:15]))+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues")
p1
```

[That code generates this plot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJlgS.png)

Answer (score 1):

I've worked out a solution using specified colours rather than RColorBrewer:

```
p1 = plot(likert(mass[,3:15]), colors = c("red", "pink", "green", "blue", "yellow"))
p1
```

[Will now produce this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoZkq.png)

If anyone has a more elegant solution that will allow RColorBrewer palettes I'd be interested to see that too.

Thanks